# How do I search by attribute in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have an extremely long Word document that outlines many other Word documents. The outline contains a mixture of headings, hyperlinked titles, and bulleted lists. Is there a way to search only the hyperlinked titles?

For example, I would have

**Story 1** [that links to that Word document on my computer]

- this happened in story 1
- story 1 happened on this date
- i have these characters in story 1
- story 1 references Ima Oneshot

When I run a keyword search for "story" I only want to bring up instances where it is a linked title, not where it was part of a bulleted list.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

#### When I search for "story" I only want to find hyperlinks

Option 1:

> **Find All Hyperlinks in a Document**
>
> 1. First, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. You can see all hyperlinks turn into their "Link" parts now.
> 2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>” to open the "Find and Replace" dialog box.
> 3. Click "Find".
> 4. Then type `^d HYPERLINK` in "Find what" text box.
> 5. Next click "Reading Highlight".
> 6. Choose Highlight All.
>
> [image]
>
> 7. Then all the hyperlinks will be highlighted.
> 8. You can also click "Find Next" button to locate each hyperlink one by one.

Source: [How to Find, Change and Delete Hyperlinks in Your Word Document](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/find-change-delete-hyperlinks-word-document/)

Option 2:

> 1. Open the Microsoft Word document. Click "Edit" on the navigation bar and select "Find." This opens a "Find and replace" dialog box.
> 2. Choose the "More" button at the bottom of the box. This expands the box to reveal more options.
> 3. Click the "Format" button and select "Style." Scroll through the list of styles in the "Find Style" box and select "Hyperlink." Click
>    "OK" to close the box.
> 4. Select the "Find next" button. The program highlights the first instance of a hyperlink. Repeat this step to see the remaining
>    hyperlinks in the document. The program will alert you with a message
>    when it has finished searching the document.

Source: [How to Find Hyperlinks in a Word Document |](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-find-hyperlinks-in-a-word-document)